# PySimpleSoap and wsdl

Tags: wsdl, python-3.4, soap-client, pysimplesoap

I'm trying to integrate with the following web service:
    http://demo.eu.yellowfin.com.au/services/AdministrationService?wsdl

unfortunately I haven't found any information about pysimplesoap that can help me to figure out how I can make a request in my case:

I got so far as this:

```
from pysimplesoap.client import SoapClient


yellowfin_url = 'http://demo.eu.yellowfin.com.au/services/AdministrationService?wsdl'
c = SoapClient(wsdl=yellowfin_url, soap_ns='soap', trace=False)

req = c.services['AdministrationServiceService']['ports']['AdministrationService']['operations']['remoteAdministrationCall']['input']['remoteAdministrationCallRequest']

req['in0']['loginId'] = 'admin@yellowfin.com.au'
req['in0']['password'] = 'test'
req['in0']['function'] = 'LOGINUSER'
req['in0']['orgId'] = 1
req['in0']['person']['userId'] = 'myuser@user.com'
req['in0']['person']['password'] = 'reset123'

resp = c.remoteAdministrationCall()
```

there is no way I can get the complextype to send, so I had a look at the documentation of the object and I thought that overriding the params I needed would have worked but the request I make is always empty.

I tried to pass the "undicted" payload inside as normal keyword args, didn't work...
I would use something else but this is the only lib that is compatible  with python3
I just want to know if there is something like suds where i can do:

```
c = Client(yellowfin_url, faults=False)

req = c.factory.create('AdministrationServiceRequest')
```

and get the xml object

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
response = c.remoteAdministrationCall(
    loginId='admin@yellowfin.com.au',
    password='test',
    function='LOGINUSER',
    orgId=1,
    person={'userId': 'myuser@user.com', 'password': 'reset123'}
)
```

I'm not completely sure about the person part.

You can call `c.help('remoteAdministrationCall')` to find out which parameters the operation accepts and other things.